# Pass coordinates of current Google Maps marker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

Maybe a simple question but couldn't find an easy answer for it. I have an eventhandler on my marker which makes an InfoWindow pop up with a `ng-click` inside of it:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function() {

     var contentString = "<div>Somerandomstring<br/>" +
                         "<a ng-click='send()'>Send to google maps</a></div>";

     var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);
     infowindow.setContent(compiled[0]);

     infowindow.open($scope.map, myMarker);
});
```

Is there any way I can pass the coordinates of the `myMarker` to the function `send()`? Something like `send(this.position)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the following using `myMarker.getPosition()`

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', function() {
     var location = myMarker.getPosition().toString();
     var contentString = "<div>Somerandomstring<br/>" +
                         "<a ng-click='send(" + location + ")'>Send to google maps</a></div>";

     var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);
     infowindow.setContent(compiled[0]);

     infowindow.open($scope.map, myMarker);
});
```

Comment: Of course.. I also had to split the up the location in latitude and longitude to be able to pass it without errors, but got it right now. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if the `toString` would create a latLng Literal object that they described in the api or not! Glad to see you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

The [google maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) says Marker object has a `getPosition()` method. So you could use `send(marker.getPosition())` to send the position to your controller, but I think you could find a cleaner way to do it.